# Espresso with AsyncTask

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to write a test for my SignIn Activity, in which I'm using an AsyncTask.

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .........

    new AsyncSignButton().execute();
}

class AsyncSignButton extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
   ....... 
}
```

For testing, I have tried using IdlingResource, but I do not understand how would use it with an AsyncTask, not with a WebView as in the examples, just simple a AsyncTask.

---

Here is my Test code:

```
public class Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SplashActivity> {

private SplashActivity mActivity;

public Test(){
    super(SplashActivity.class);
}

public Test(Class<SplashActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = getActivity();
    //how call it?
}

@LargeTest
public void testList() throws InterruptedException {

   //wait AsyncTask before call
   onView(withId(R.id.action_bar_accept_button)).perform(click());

}

public final class AsyncIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private AsyncTask asyncTask;
    private ResourceCallback callback;

    public AsyncIdlingResource(AsyncTask asyncTask){
        this.asyncTask = checkNotNull(asyncTask);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Sign idling resource";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        if(asyncTask == null) return true;
        return asyncTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.callback = resourceCallback;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good news, you don't need any custom IdlingResource for AsyncTask: Espresso already waits for all tasks to have run before executing actions/assertions. This is mentioned for example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html).